# Compress images before generating PDF file

Tags: files

I am working with [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) Module, and I used it to export any node of content type "Appointment" as PDF file and then send it by email...

In my case the content type "Appointment" should have a field of type "Image", so that mean I will have many images included on the PDF file.

Let's imagine that the client upload 10 images with 1MB for each one , so that will make my website so slow in generating the PDF file and maybe will not continue all the process .

I need a tool which can compress images before saving the node and that will make it easier for generating the PDF file.

Is there any solutions guys!

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way to go would probably be to create a "reduced" image style (in `admin/config/media/image-styles`) and use it for the image field in your "Appointment" content type. Like that, you would let Drupal itself do the compressing of the images.